How to get the a network adapter working with Fedora 6 on VMware Workstation?
I am experimenting with older versions of Linux in VMware. RHEL5 detects my virtual network adapter just fine, but Fedora 6 does not. I thought that RHEL5 was based on Fedora 6? I have tried various operating system options in VMware for Fedora 6, such as "Fedora", "Red Hat Linux", and "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5" without success.
I am trying to run Fedora 6 i386, if that makes a difference. I am using VMware Workstation 16.

Is there any reason to use such an outdated distro? RHEL might be based on Fedora but it has its own heavily modified kernel.

Is there an option for an e1000 (intel) emulated network card? Remembering back to those days, I think that will work.
